# how to get the id of the given row text in android from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hello friends i am new to android.well i have created a database table in that i have few rows as follows

_id     name      city

1      maddy0      xyz0

2      maddy1      xyz1

3      maddy2      xyz2

now what i want to pass a city to the function and get the row id of that city

say i pas xyz0 then it should give me that out put as 1 .for that i tried this

```
public String getDatatonumber(String s) {
    Cursor c = null;
    String result = new String();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
    try {
        c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
                "select _id from quotes_internal where text ='"+s+"';", null);
        // Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE_LOGICAL, columns,
        // null, null, null, null, null);

        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

            result=(" " + c.getInt(iName));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I put this code in the database helper class and from the main activity I am calling it as

```
results =new String();
results=db.getDatatonumber(texts).trim();
text.settext(results);
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong I am passing the same values which are there in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to user LIKE Operator while comparing with Text

```
c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("select _id from quotes_internal where text LIKE '" + s.trim() + "';", null );
```

Comment: well krish it is showing nothing .well i am trying to show that numbe in a text view .in that it is showing blank .that is no data bro

Answer (score 0):

```
c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
            "select _id from quotes_internal where city='"+s+"';", null);



for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        result=(" " + c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    }
```

this will return your row id